# Join query in Moodle only returns last column only while mysql returns correctly

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, moodle

I have 2 tables in my moodle database such as equiz_details and equiz_responses as follows:

**mdl_equiz_details:**

[image]

**mdl_equiz_details**

[image]

I have used a join query to fetch result as desired form as follows:

```
SELECT distinct ed.quizid,ed.questionnumber,ed.questiontext,ed.optiontext1,ed.optiontext2,ed.optiontext3,ed.optiontext4, ed.correctanswer,er.studentanswer FROM `mdl_equiz_details` as ed INNER JOIN `mdl_equiz_responses` as er ON ed.quizid = er.quizid and ed.questionnumber = er.questionnumber and er.studentid=4 and er.quizid=25
```

I fired the query in mysql database annd got result as follows:

**Result in mysql**

[image]

I am using the same query inside my moodle page and try to fetch result as follows::

```
<?php
require_once('../../config.php');
global $DB; 

$quizresdetails = $DB->get_records_sql("SELECT ed.quizid,ed.questionnumber,ed.questiontext,ed.optiontext1,ed.optiontext2,ed.optiontext3,ed.optiontext4, ed.correctanswer,er.studentanswer FROM {equiz_details} ed INNER JOIN {equiz_responses} er ON ed.quizid = er.quizid and ed.questionnumber = er.questionnumber and er.studentid=4 and er.quizid=25");      

var_dump($quizresdetails);

?>
```

I am getting the result as follows:

**Result in Moodle page**

[image]

Which is obviously the last result.

What I am doing wrong? How can I fetch full result in my moodle page?

**Moodle version: 2.9.1**

Comment: On the surface I don't see a ***loop*** iterating though each record within the recordset.  Something like [this moodle example](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=136366) `$records = get_records_sql('insert your query in here');
foreach ($records as $record) {
...(Display code here)...}`

Comment: @xQbert please check my code above I am doing the same. My query is returning 10 columns. But in my moodle page it returns only last record. When I took count then also getting 1.

Comment: I see no place where you LOOP... `FOREACH` in the above code.  check the example again vs your code.  Please indicate where your loop is.

Comment: @xQbert I had taken var_dump() and count($record) as well. count returns 1 but I have 10 records. And var_dump() only gives last record as you can see in image above!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your query is returning the same value for its id in each record: "25". The Moodle get_records_* methods expect every result to have a unique id, as it uses that id as the array key in the array of results it returns. So it's finding all your results, but as it loops through them it is adding each result to the array key "25", so then when it gets to the end, it only has the last result in the returned array.

So you need to return a field with a unique id for each row, as "id".

Comment: Buddy I just removed the first ed.quizid now it works fine. You ara amazing. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Hi, That will mean it is using the questionnumber field as the id for the array key, whilst that should work if you run the query against a specific quizid, it would be better to return the actual "ed.id" as the first column just to be safe and make sure it is always returning unique rows, I would have thought. Though I don't have that plugin so I can't test it myself.